# Can't import jwt-decode in JavaScript file in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I created a React app and I try to make a separate file for functions.
I required 'jwt-decode' library like that:

```
const jwt_decode = require("jwt-decode");
```

After that I used it like that:

```
const verifyToken = (token) => { console.log(jwt_decode(token)); };
```

And exported like that:

```
module.exports = { verifyToken };
```

When I tried to use it in my react page, I saw this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jwt_decode is not a function
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: I'm calling the function like that: import { verifyToken } from '../utils/checkJwt';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use CommonJS require syntax in a React app that is likely using ES6 import syntax.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

const verifyToken = (token) => { console.log(jwt_decode(token)); };

export default { verifyToken };
```

And then in your React page, use:

```
import verifyToken from './path/to/your/file';
```

It works to me!

Answer (score 2):

You need to require the default export:

```js
const { default: jwt_decode } = require("jwt-decode");

const token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";
console.log(jwt_decode(token));
```

Expected output:

```
{ sub: '1234567890', name: 'John Doe', iat: 1516239022 }
```

Alternatively use `import` when `type` in `package.json` is set to `module`.

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

const token = "eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token";
const decoded = jwtDecode(token);
```

it would help if you imported like these in the react-app
for more info go through this official doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode#documentation